# Length of Array returning "undefined"

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-controller

I am building an application using AngularJS. I use Slim for handling web service in my application.

I have a service like:

```js
angular.module('MyApp').
factory('MainPage', function($resource,BASE_URL){
    return $resource("my api call", {}, {query: {method:'GET'}, isArray:true});
}).
```

From Slim I am returning a json response like:

```php
$resposedat = array("value1"=>"val1","value2"=>"val2"); 
echo json_encode($resposedat);
```

In my controller I have written:

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp')

app.controller('MainCtrl',function($scope,MainPage,$rootScope){
    $scope.mainpage = MainPage.query();
    
    console.info($scope.mainpage);
    console.info($scope.mainpage.length);//undefined
});
```

My console looks like this for `console.info($scope.mainpage)`

> Resource {$get: function, $save: function, $query: function, $remove: function, $delete: function…}
>
> value1: "val1"
>
> value2: "val2"

And my console returning `undefined` for `console.info($scope.mainpage.length)`

What am i doing here wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MainPage.query()` is asynchronous, so your array does not exist, hence does not have a `length` property at the time you call it.

The value `$scope.mainpage` holds until the data has been retrieved is something called a `promise`. It serves as a temporary placeholder.